# Place Single Dot With Vim/Ex

Tags: vim, ex

I'm messing around with vim one liners, and I'm unable to escape a . character in a vim ex mode append command.

Basically,

```
vim -En '+a|Hello World' '+p' '+q!' -
```

prints "Hello World"

But,

```
vim -En '+a|.' '+p' '+q!' -
```

prints nothing at all.  The . on a line by itself ends the append command, so I can't print it.

This unfortunately means I can't write a vim -E command script allowing me to chain commands.  I want something like this, where the first vim call constructs the Ex commands, and the second interprets them

```
vim -En '+a|aConvoluted Hello World
.
Qp
QZQ
' | vim -En
```

But the first call fails: everything from the . on is ignored.

Any way to escape the dot?  (It's a bit of a code golf, so it's all got to be vim only)

Golf rules for those who are interested:

> No characters from the set b,c,d,e,f,k,p,r,s,t,{,},$,&,;,/,:,@,#,,,(,),<,>,!
>  All uppercase characters are allowed.

Comment: did you try `\.` ?

Comment: Fraid so :(.  You have to drop the single quotes and escape the pipe or bash goes crazy, but vim still doesn't care.  +a\|\. prints nothing, +a\|\\. prints \.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a bit contrived but it outputs a single period for me:

```
vim -En '+a|.x' '+s/x//' '+p' '+q!' -
```

(You mentioned golf so maybe this won't work for you since it adds a relatively large number of characters. Be sure to detail any specific constraints if you have any.)

Comment: This is a good one, adds a letter then removes it.  If there's a cleaner way to remove letters, it might satisfy the rules I'm under.